# How to hook before iron-router changes the current route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I work on a form where my user upload files to S3. If the user leave the form without validating it, even if files are uploaded, the files upload should be canceled and the files deleted from S3.

I have no trouble deleting the files from my S3 bucket. However, I need to be able to delete them *before* the user leaves the current route (i.e. page) and skip it if the next route is the same page (i.e. a page refresh).

This is an issue very similar to [this one on Github](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/698) where they say that, basically, it can't be done. [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977244/meteors-iron-router-alter-path-before-routing) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532018/iron-router-hook-on-a-route-before-actually-changing-the-template) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984651/iron-router-route-allow-deny) questions are in SO too, but none offers a satisfying answer.

I wanted to check if it is possible here, since it seems to me that this is a vital feature and I expect that other people may have dealt with it before.

If it can't be done, what workaround would you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a great trick to detect when the user leave the current page. Here is the recipe:

- Attach a subscription (even if empty) to your route controller. This way, `route loaded` = `subscription active` and `route left` = `subscription stopped`
- Add an `onStop()` function and put inside it all the server side code you need to execute when the user leave the page. here is how my publication looks (I delete uploaded files when the related form hasn't been submitted when page is left):

  ```
  Meteor.publish("files", function(sessionId) {
    var self = this;

    // Here I clean all the files I need to remove because the user has
    // not submitted the current form. 
    self.onStop(function () {
        console.log (sessionId + " is cleaning...");
        cleanFiles(sessionId)
    });

    // I look for files related to the current upload session only
    if(Users.isInRoles(this.userId, ["user"])) {
      return Files.find({"session_id":sessionId, "owner":this.userId}, {});
    }
    //and I make my publication available in case the if statement failed
    return self.ready();
  });
  ```

***Bottom line:*** *as far as I know, it works like a charm. This is a great way to keep track of the user activity and execute code once he leaves the page or a sub-page (whatever template route we attached the subscription to).*

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the client temporarily loses websocket connectivity, then this will execute. That means if the user's wifi drops for a couple seconds, he loses his progress.

Comment: @Matt K, I freaked out for a minute. I just made a few tries and it does not trigger the onStop immediatly. There is a 30 second delay before the upload fail completly. If I reconnect within the 10 sec, the upload resumes. If I do between 10 and 30, it restarts. After the 30 sec, I get an "upload failed" error message. FYI I use the slingshot package for the upload.

Comment: The onStop() triggers, if I don't reconnect, after a 42 (?) second delay. This is as soon as I get a socket error `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

Comment: So if they upload a picture successfully & then are disconnected for 43 seconds, is that picture deleted when they reconnect?

Comment: yes if the form has not been submitted. The user interface display a feedback "upload failed" when user comes back. I agree that it isn't ideal, but this is just an early version. I will probably timestamp my generated upload session Id and prevent its files from being deleted until it expires or the user comes back. That should make it more usable. However, it looks like a corner case to me (not that I don't want to deal with it).

Comment: OK, I don't get my feedback when user comes back after the `onStop()` run. And it appears that during a deco,  the `onStop()` can trigger before I lose the socket connection. That might require extra code.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds really hard, what if the user exits the browser or their computer loses power? There's NO way to ensure that you could execute code on the client before the browser closed, so you need something on the server.

I don't know your whole process flow, but I imagine you're doing something like uploading a profile pic for a new account & if the account isn't created, then delete it. I'd recommend something like a staging area. They upload the pic & in your database you have the s3 url & a `confirmed` flag. The confirm flag defaults to false, and toggles when the form is saved. Then, you run a cron job every hour/day/week on every new picture that was uploaded & delete those that aren't confirmed.

This has the added benefit that if they accidentally close the browser, you are a champ & saved their progress.

Comment: I planned to run a cron job on server for the cases where I can't track the abortion of the process, but I expected these cases to be "rare" enough to allow me to use a large periodicity cron job (i.e. every week). However, systematizing it and reducing its periodicity to 24h could do the trick, and it is much simpler than the iron-router solution. Not to mention that it shouldn't be such a load. The "resumable" feature makes it even nicer, I didn't think of that :-) I'll validate your answer. Thanks!